# VBA using part of formula as a celll value

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, find, match

Failing againg with my project

I have formulas with variable Brand that is changed dynamically (AF Column). Basically all I want is to extract Brands into a column next (AE) to the formula column for visial convenience

```
For i = LBound(Brand) To UBound(Brand)
        Range("AF" & i + 2).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & _
                   ",H:H,""Headphones"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"
  Next i

Range("AF:AF").Sort Key1:=Range("AF2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
ActiveSheet.Range("AG2:AG8").Formula = ActiveSheet.Range("AF2:AF8").Formula
ActiveSheet.Range("AH2:AH8").Formula = ActiveSheet.Range("AF2:AF8").Formula

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Dim j As Variant
j = Application.Match(""" & Brand(i) & """, ws.Range("AF2:AF8"))
ActiveSheet.Range("AE2").Value = Application.Index(ws.Range("AF2:AF8"), j, 0)
```

And I get #N/A Already lost two days for that. Would be enourmously grateful to anyone who could help.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see where the error is occurring?

Comment: Also, when you load `j` with the `Application.Match` result, you're using `i` which is not inside a loop so will be set to the **last** value in the previous `For..Next..` loop.

Comment: Would help a lot to include an example of the formulas you're trying to extract from.

Comment: @TimWilliams the formula is in the code  "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & _
                   ",H:H,""Headphones"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"

Comment: @CLR there is no mistakes in the codes currently, it just doesn not return the right vlaue - the Brand that is used in  "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & _ ",H:H,""Headphones"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")" formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from your question as to your desired output but here's a guess:

```
For i = LBound(Brand) To UBound(Brand)
    Range("AF" & i + 2).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & _
               ",H:H,""Headphones"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"
    Range("AE" & i + 2).Value = Brand(i)
Next i
Range("AE:AF").Sort Key1:=Range("AF2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

I've added a line to write the brand to AE, and altered the `Sort` to accommodate this.